# How to copy a trained FindMatch ML transform in AWS Glue from UAT to PROD environment in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I have been recently using a FindMatch ML Transform in AWS to help find duplicate records in a given dataset. To create the ml transform I had to go to AWS Glue and get it created. To use the transform I had to train it manually by generating a label file and using it to train the transform. And in order to use the transform I have created a AWS Glue Job on top of the transform. I have a requirement that tomorrow when I have to move this trained ml transform from one environment to another like from UAT to PROD, how should I approach it. The thing is when i train the ml transform definitely it would be saving the trained information somewhere in AWS like in an S3 location or in memory. If I could find that location where the trainings could have been stored, I could copy that data to the new AWS environment, create a new ml transform and attach that copied data to the ml transform. This way it could save me from doing the retraining work of ml transform again on PROD environment.

I have one way in mind that I can save the labelling files I had used for training the transform in UAT, use the same labelling files to train the ml transform in PROD AWS. Do please let me know if there is another way to do this, actually curious to know if I can find the location of the trained data of the ml transform, get it copied to the new environment and attach it to the new ml transform in PROD AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution, we have to use the label files only, thing is we can export the label files from the transform in UAT and use the exported label file to train the transform in prod.